How to use clangd as formatter in neovim?
I am using nvim with lazy and using mason, mason-lspconfig, nvim-lspconfig as follow
return {
        {
                "williamboman/mason.nvim",
                config = function()
                        require("mason").setup()
                end,
        },
        {
                "williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim",
                config = function()
                        require("mason-lspconfig").setup({
                                ensure_installed = { "lua_ls" },
                        })
                end,
        },
        {
                "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
                lazy = false,
                config = function()
                        local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")
                        local capabilities = require("cmp_nvim_lsp").default_capabilities()
                        lspconfig.lua_ls.setup({
                                capabilities = capabilities,
                        })
                        lspconfig.clangd.setup({
                                capabilities = capabilities,
                        })

                        vim.keymap.set({ "n", "v" }, "<leader>ca", vim.lsp.buf.code_action, {})
                        vim.keymap.set("n", "K", vim.lsp.buf.hover, {})
                        vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>e", function()
                                vim.diagnostic.open_float(0, { scope = "line" })
                        end, {})
                end,
        },
}

The above setting works fine for c++ except that I cannot format the code using clangd so I followed some guide and set clang-format as the formatter using none-ls as follow:
return {
        "nvimtools/none-ls.nvim",
        config = function()
                local null_ls = require("null-ls")
                null_ls.setup({
                        sources = {
                                null_ls.builtins.formatting.stylua,
                                null_ls.builtins.formatting.black,
                                null_ls.builtins.formatting.isort,
                                null_ls.builtins.formatting.clang_format,
                        },
                })
                vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>F", vim.lsp.buf.format, {})
        end,
}

However I believed that clang-format is formatting differently than clangd. I feel that using clangd format in vscode keep the code easier to read and most of the legacy project is formatted using that way so when applying clang-format, it creates a bunch of unnecessary change.
I want to set up clangd as formatter similar to vscode setting to avoid unnecessary changes
Thanks

In my Configuration i depend on lsp-zero to easily perform format on save using clangd for C/C++ and rust-analyzer for rust
config = function()
    local lsp_zero = require("lsp-zero")
    lsp_zero.format_on_save({
        format_opts = {
            async = true,
            timeout_ms = 10000,
        },
        servers = {
            ['rust-analyzer'] = { 'rust' }
            ['clangd'] = { 'c', 'cpp' },
        }
    })
end

